# cannot resolve hostname (raspbian)

Tags: networking, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hostname

I have my hostname declared within /etc/environment as MYHOSTNAME=thisisaname

If I use this variable in the config files I get an error.

```
# cat /etc/hostname
$MYHOSTNAME

# cat /etc/hosts

stuff..

127.0.0.1.1 $MYHOSTNAME
```

Next I do sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh

With every sudo I do I get the error:
cannot resolve hostname

I know that you get this error when the value in hostname is not the same as in hosts. I do not understand why because the /etc/environment file is loaded correctly.

Can somebody help me with this?

I want the hostname in a variable because I am making a config script which enables to set the hostname permanently.

Comment: /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts are simple files, they are not shell like, so $MYHOSTNAME is just ... well $MYHOSTNAME. you would perhaps want to have a script that generate those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

populate /etc/hosts on the fly based on hostname content ...

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts
```

or on HOSTNAME value :

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts
```

/etc/hostname and /etc/hosts don't accept variables, they are bare text files.